# Getting kind mis-match error when trying to use existential quantification

Tags: haskell, types

Would like to declare

```
data (Coord a) => Triangle a = Triangle{t0 :: a, t1 :: a, t2 :: a}
```

However I am getting

> Geometry.hs:15:19:Kind mis-match
>       Expected kind `* -> *', but`p' has kind `*'
>       In the class declaration for`Coord'

where Coord is defined as

```
class (Traversable p, Functor p, Foldable p, Applicative p) => Coord p where

getComponents :: Num a => p a -> [a]
getComponents = toList

fromComponents :: Num a => [a] -> p a

magSq :: Num a => p a -> a
magSq = Prelude.sum . map (\x -> x * x) . getComponents

dotProduct :: Num a => p a -> p a -> a
dotProduct a b = Prelude.sum $ zipWith (*) (getComponents a) (getComponents b)
```

Any ideas?

PS. Code is a slightly modified version of what is found in the Data.SG package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
data (Coord p, Num a) => Triangle p a = Triangle {t0 :: p a, t1 :: p a, t2 :: p a}
```

In short, a type that has the typeclass `Coord` is a parameterized type. You have to supply the parameter.

(The *kind* of a type tells you whether it has any parameters. Types of kind `*` can have actual values. All other types are parameterized. Any type that has the typeclass `Coord` is of kind `* -> *`, which means it takes one argument of kind `*`.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot just to see if it works, but after reading more it seems like it is bad form to put that quantifier in the constructor anyway, because then it requires a similar quantification  on all the function signatures, or something like that.